# NPM still gives warnings, npm audix fix not working

Tags: npm, audit

My project's package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-register": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "build": "^0.1.4",
    "jsdom": "^14.0.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nyc": "^13.1.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "webpack": "^4.12.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "yargs": "^13.2.2"
},
```

When I run "npm i", I still see:

```
audited 14173 packages in 5.084s
found 6 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 moderate, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

When I run "npm audit":

```
                       === npm audit security report ===                        
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
                                                                                
          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           
                                                                                
                                                                                
  Moderate        Denial of Service                                             
                                                                                
  Package         js-yaml                                                       
                                                                                
  Patched in      >=3.13.0                                                      
                                                                                
  Dependency of   build                                                         
                                                                                
  Path            build > jxLoader > js-yaml                                    
                                                                                
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/788                              
                                                                                
                                                                                
  Critical        Deserialization Code Execution                                
                                                                                
  Package         js-yaml                                                       
                                                                                
  Patched in      >= 2.0.5                                                      
                                                                                
  Dependency of   build                                                         
                                                                                
  Path            build > jxLoader > js-yaml                                    
                                                                                
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/16                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
  Low             Incorrect Handling of Non-Boolean Comparisons During          
                  Minification                                                  
                                                                                
  Package         uglify-js                                                     
                                                                                
  Patched in      >= 2.4.24                                                     
                                                                                
  Dependency of   build                                                         
                                                                                
  Path            build > uglify-js                                             
                                                                                
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/39                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
                                                                                
  Package         uglify-js                                                     
                                                                                
  Patched in      >=2.6.0                                                       
                                                                                
  Dependency of   build                                                         
                                                                                
  Path            build > uglify-js                                             
                                                                                
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/48                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
                                                                                
  Package         braces                                                        
                                                                                
  Patched in      >=2.3.1                                                       
                                                                                
  Dependency of   babel-register                                                
                                                                                
  Path            babel-register > babel-core > micromatch > braces             
                                                                                
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786                              
                                                                                
                                                                                
  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
                                                                                
  Package         timespan                                                      
                                                                                
  Patched in      No patch available                                            
                                                                                
  Dependency of   build                                                         
                                                                                
  Path            build > timespan                                              
                                                                                
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/533
```

When I try to run "npm audit fix" it say:

```
up to date in 4.704s
fixed 0 of 6 vulnerabilities in 14173 scanned packages
  6 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

I already tried to delete the "package-lock.json" file and try again, already tried to clear npm cache, and tried to update the packages manually, none of these steps seems to be working. Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it myself, updated all packages to the latest version manually, and removed the "build": "^0.1.4" package, since it no longer updates.